# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, error-handling, create-table

```
"CREATE TABLE registration(firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,middlename VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,date DATE(),radio enum('male','female') NOT NULL,fatherfirstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,fathermiddlename VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,fatherlastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,address text() NOT NULL,city VARCHAR(30),state VARCHAR(30),zip INT(20),country VARCHAR(30),email VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL UNIQUE,phone INT(10))";
```

After excuting above query below error will be displayed.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '"CREATE TABLE registration1(firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT
>   NULL,middlename VARCHAR(30' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

there is **syntax error** here

```
date DATE() and address text()
```

**-> remove `()`**
and use below code:

```
CREATE TABLE registration (firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,middlename VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,date DATE,radio enum('male','female') NOT NULL,fatherfirstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,fathermiddlename VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,fatherlastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,address text NOT NULL,city VARCHAR(30),state VARCHAR(30),zip INT(20),country VARCHAR(30),email VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL UNIQUE,phone INT(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

And also UNIQE is nit correct:

```
CREATE TABLE registration(
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
middlename VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,DATE DATE,
radio ENUM('male','female') NOT NULL,
fatherfirstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
fathermiddlename VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
fatherlastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
address TEXT NOT NULL,city VARCHAR(30),
state VARCHAR(30),zip INT(20),
country VARCHAR(30),
email VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
-- UNIQUE,
phone INT(10)
)
```